# SQL Query - how to have half-split column within the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask if it is possible to do a query and have a result like this? The more difficult part is to have a half-split column within the same row.

M stands for Male and F stands for Female for those who are wondering.

```
Teacher Class  Level   Name            7      8       9       10     11 
                                      M F   M   F   M   F   M   F   M   F
Mr A    Class  1       Ant            0 0   3   9   0   1   0   0   0   0
Ms B    Class  1       Bumble Bee     0 0   11  5   1   0   0   0   0   0
Mrs C   Class  2       Cat            0 0   0   1   7   1   0   0   0   0
Mdm D   Class  3       Dog            0 0   0   0   0   0   7   0   1   0
```

I have attached the same table but in excel so it's easier to see. It will be good if this can be done in pure sql query.
[image: Table]
Thank you in advance to those who help in any way.

Comment: This is a presentation issue and nothing for SQL. Handle it in your program.

Comment: Please show your database tables , or show what you try so far

Comment: Mysql store relations, not excell tables. There are no merged columns in relations.

Answer (score 0):

The closest result you could get solely using SQL would be to have a table returned with the following column headers:

`Teacher Name, Class Level, Name, 7_M, 7_F,8_M, 8_F,9_M, 9_F,10_M, 10_F,11_M, 11_F`.

Now, to display those X_M and X_F column as "half-split", you would have to do it outside SQL (EDIT: For the reasons Radim mentioned in his comment).